# Storing comma values for percentage in sql 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I got a numeric column in my database for storing discount percentages for my items.

If the discount is 25,6 it will remove the 6.

What kind of type does this column have to be to not remove the number behind ,?
And what is best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're talking about the [`decimal` data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx).

The decimal definition is split into two parts...

- the first is the TOTAL number of digits that you want to store, both to the left and the right of the decimal character (normally `.` or `,`). This is called the `precision`.
- the second is the number of digits to the right of the decimal character. This is called the `scale`.

For instance, to store a percentage with 1 decimal place (such as the `25,6` you give as an example), you would use the following

```
decimal(4,1)
```

That means that you have a maximum of 4 digits, with only 1 of those digits being **after** the decimal place.  It would have a maximum storage of `999.9`

Comment: Cool, ill test it right away. Very nice explanation :)

Comment: Im sorry boss, i will check. I think it still received the wrong numbers but i may have to put all the data in again. I give you a answer soon. Hope you have a good weekend.